# survfit results:: all the events number are 0 even if there are indicator=1

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Could anyone please help me with this issue? I am running survfit function however the events number shows 0 for all groups. Here is the output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDXSY.png)

Here are my codes:

```
require("survival")
fit <- survfit(formula=Surv(duration2, Lps_Cnt) ~ NEW_COLUMN, data = recreateds)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = recreateds)
print(fit)
```

Comment: Please, could you share the output of the command `print(recreateds)`?

Comment: Hi Marco, thank you for the reply!! I figured out the solution: I have to cast the data to integer in order for the survfit to recognize the event.